asyncio program with qasync and PySide6 - when can I start scheduling tasks in the event loop?
I launch my program using the following:
async def main():
    logger.info('client app starting')
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    with loop:
        loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initLogging(fileName=os.path.join('log','client.log'))
    asyncio.run(main())

In the __init__ method of MainWindow I was scheduling some tasks in the event loop. But they weren't running until I closed the main window. So then I tried scheduling them in the showEvent event on the main window but that also didn't work. Then I triggered it using a pushbutton and it did work but that's undesirable because I want them to be triggered automatically. When can I start adding tasks to the event loop and which event can I use to do so?
python 3.12
PySide 6.7.3
qasync 0.27.1

Here is a working example. Note that hello prints after the main window is closed.
import sys
import asyncio
from qasync import QApplication, QEventLoop
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel

async def hello():
    print('hello')

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Client App')

        task = asyncio.create_task(hello())

        self.label = QLabel('Main Window')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        print('main window show event')
        task = asyncio.create_task(hello())
    
    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        print('main window focus in event')

async def main():
    print('app starting')
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    with loop:
        loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


add await task.

It would be a lot simpler to use a single-shot timer and get rid of all the asyncio cruft. Do you have a genuine use-case for employing asyncio in a PySide/PyQt application, or is this just curiosity?

@ekhumoro yes my app needs to integrate with other asyncio components (ie asyncio server, opc client, etc)

@eyllanesc where and how?

@iamthebull While there are cases for which async-based solutions are justified (or even required), a similar approach should be chosen only when necessary and as long as it makes sense. Right now your code is just based on a print statement, which makes async an unnecessary complexity. As far as we know, you may just be facing an XY problem, so please [edit] your post and provide either a more appropriate [mre] that closely resembles your case, or a clear explanation for which you must use async.

My sample code reproduces EXACTLY the behavior which my question is addressing. It is about understanding the event loop and WHEN tasks are scheduled and executed not WHY. It is irrelevant what they do when they get there. Clearly I would not be using asyncio ONLY to print statements to the console.

@iamthebull I understand the question, but on SO we also try to avoid answering questions caused by unrelated issues (the XY problem above); that may not be your case, but that's exactly the reason for which knowing what you do in those tasks is relevant: we know nothing about your program or experience, and while we can assume that you wouldn't just do that for print statements, we cannot know what you actually use that for, which may or may not be a valid approach. You also have to understand the purpose of SO and how uncontextualized questions may affect research done by others.

This is not an X Y problem because this question is not about solving a particular problem. It's about understanding the functionality of components themselves. I've very clearly identified certain functionality that I would like to understand more outside of any context. I don't see what is so wrong about that and why this platform is so against just pure curiosity.

@mkrieger1 True. He is commenting as if he speaks on behalf of the platform though...

@iamthebull No, I'm not, and I specifically wrote that "it may not be your case" exactly because it wasn't clear. In your question you referred to "a program" with a possibly specific case, and there was no mention about wanting to understand the underlying aspects (which is a perfectly valid question), until you wrote that in the comments. We get lots of posts every day that are based on inaccurate assumptions or simply ask the "wrong question", and our efforts are to help people with the actual problem instead of arbitrarily providing answers that may not actually solve the real issue.

I found a workaround here. Code for MainWindow is
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Client App')

        self.label = QLabel('Main Window')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.ready)

    @asyncSlot()
    async def ready(self):
        task = asyncio.create_task(hello())

    def showEvent(self, event):
        print('main window show event')

